# how to scroll table horizontally in android

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to implement table layout in android.I have table Header and row designed in one xml file and am passing data using adapter.So What is happening is I got scrolling horizontally but with multiple table header repeating on each row.
What I want to achieve is table header should be seen only once and all the rows below it should scroll along with table header.

Here's my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<HorizontalScrollView  android:id="@+id/horizontalView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:divider="@color/black"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    >
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Type"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Fare"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Tax"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Airline Pnr"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Ticekt Numner"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/name"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/type"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fare"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tax"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/air_pnr"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ticket"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_bx"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="CANCEL" />
    </TableRow>


   </TableLayout>
   </HorizontalScrollView>
```

And here's the image what it looks like[scrolling table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPHfg.png)

UPDATE (2) HERE's Adapter Code

```
public class Flight_cancel_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
public static ArrayList<Flight_cancel_Details> rowItems;
public static int available_seats;
public static PolicyAdapter adapter;
int TOTAL;
public static ArrayList<String> arraySeat=new ArrayList<String>();

    Flight_cancel_Adapter(Context context,  ArrayList<Flight_cancel_Details> rowItems) {

    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = rowItems;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

/* private view holder class */
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView type;
    TextView fare;
    TextView tax;
    TextView air_pnr;
    TextView ticket;
    TextView namee;
    CheckBox box;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    holder.namee = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    holder.type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);
    holder.fare = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fare);
    holder.tax = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tax);
    holder.air_pnr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.air_pnr);
    holder.ticket = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ticket);
    holder.box = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_bx);
    holder.box.setTag(position);


    try
    {
        final Flight_cancel_Details row_pos = rowItems.get(position);
        String name=String.valueOf(row_pos.getName());
        String typ=String.valueOf(row_pos.gettypes());
        String far=String.valueOf(row_pos.getfares());
        String tax=String.valueOf(row_pos.gettax());
        String pnr=String.valueOf(row_pos.getair_pnr());
        String ticket=String.valueOf(row_pos.getticket());


        System.out.print("ROW POS-"+row_pos.getStatus());
        if(row_pos.getStatus().equals("CANCELLED"))
        {
            holder.namee.setText(name);
            holder.type.setText(typ);
            holder.fare.setText(far);
            holder.tax.setText(tax);
            holder.air_pnr.setText(pnr);
            holder.ticket.setText(ticket);

            holder.box.setEnabled(false);
            holder.box.setText("CANCELLED");

        }else {

            holder.namee.setText(name);
            holder.type.setText(typ);
            holder.fare.setText(far);
            holder.tax.setText(tax);
            holder.air_pnr.setText(pnr);
            holder.ticket.setText(ticket);

            holder.box.setEnabled(true);
            holder.box.setText("CANCEL");
        }
        if(row_pos.getTarvel_Status().equals("TRAVELLED"))
        {
            holder.namee.setText(name);
            holder.type.setText(typ);
            holder.fare.setText(far);
            holder.tax.setText(tax);
            holder.air_pnr.setText(pnr);
            holder.ticket.setText(ticket);

        }




    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("BUS_CANCEL_ADAP ERROR:", e.getMessage());
    }
    convertView.setTag(holder);

    holder.box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           if(isChecked) {
               int position = (int) buttonView.getTag();
               System.out.println("--CLICKED--" + position);
               String contactId = (holder.air_pnr.getText().toString());
               System.out.println("--VALUE--" + contactId);
               arraySeat.add(contactId);
           }
           else
               {
                   int position = (int) buttonView.getTag();
                   System.out.println("--UNCHEKED--" + position);
                   String contactId = (holder.air_pnr.getText().toString());
                   System.out.println("--UNCHEKED VALUE--" + contactId);
                   arraySeat.remove(contactId);
               }
        }
    });


    return convertView;

}
}
```

Comment: Could you try to put header row only once and all other rows to have data rows. Enclose entire table in scrollview

Comment: post your adapter code.

Comment: i have posted my adapter code @MohammedFarhan

Comment: the best way use horizontal recycleview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Recyclerview for horizontal scrollview for a better performance

test.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="name"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:id="@+id/name"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

recyclerview.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView  android:id="@+id/horizontalView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:listitem="@layout/layout">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my XML file, you should put title for all row `TableView` (TextView) on `LinearLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView  android:id="@+id/horizontalView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--Title for all row, once for all row -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="Type"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="Fare"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="Tax"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="Airline Pnr"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="Ticekt Numner"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:divider="@color/black"
            android:showDividers="middle"
            >
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="My Name"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:id="@+id/name"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/type"
                    android:text="My Type"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/fare"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/tax"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/air_pnr"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ticket"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/check_bx"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:text="CANCEL" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```